# Passing input stream around?

Tags: java, inputstream

I am reading email attachments with javax.mail
I want to be able to pass the attachments from one class to the other
I am reading the attachment as
               part.getInputStream();

and other classes use Input stream as input
I am debating should create

```
AttachmentClass
    inputStream
```

Or

```
AttachmentClass
    byte[]
```

I know that passing InputStream might cause leaks and point to other objects not yours, while byte array will be the actual object.

The first option will be very simple:

```
AttachmentClass.setAttachment( part.getInputStream())
NextClass.doSomething(AttachmentClass)
NextClass.doSomething(AttachmentClass)
```

the second option will require conversion from InputStream to byte and vice-versa multiple times

```
AttachmentClass.setAttachment(convertToByte(part.getInputStream()))
NextClass.doSomething(ConvertToInputStream(AttachmentClass))
NextClass.doSomething(ConvertToInputStream(AttachmentClass))
```

what is the correct way to pass InputStream around?

Comment: Have you tested both options? What happens if you try to read an InputStream twice?

Comment: Use the InputStream, but consider making `AttachmentClass` immutable.  The object which created the `AttachmentClass` instance, which has the unwrapped `InputStream` instance, is responsible for closing the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is fine as long as you remember to close the `InputStream` in `NextClass`. The conversion in the second option is moot as you convert the `InputStream` object to `byte` array, only to convert it back to `InputStream` while calling it from the second class. If you can process the attachment in it's `byte` array form in `NextClass`, then the second option is worth it.